# Difference between 楽しくやってます and 楽しくやれてます

Tags: meaning

In the below exchange how does the meaning of 楽しくやれてます differ from  if 楽しくやってます was used? I know that the former is in the potential form, whilst the latter is in the plain form but I'm not quite sure the difference in nuance.

To provide some context for the below exchange, the person was on the phone with someone and talking about how things have been going so far.

> 仲間同士での問題はありますか？
>
> 今はないです。藍咲と実乃璃が仲悪いかな。 それくらいです
>
> あの二人は大変そうですね。 暴力沙汰にはなってませんか？
>
> それはないですよ。境子も実乃璃が悪さしたら日本に送りかえすって言ってますし
>
> 今のところは楽しくやれてます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is small, but the potential form tends to be used when he feels he is involved or concerned. If he has made an active effort to make things work well, it emphasizes his effort.

- 今のところは楽しくやっています。
  I'm doing well so far.
- 今のところは楽しくやれています。
  I'm managing well so far.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How would you say it when even more effort is involved? Would 「楽しいやろうとする」 make sense?

Comment: @Garbaz 楽しいやろう makes no sense to me. 何とか楽しくすることができています is "Somehow I have managed to have fun so far".